# How to customize AWSUserPoolSignIn?

Tags: aws-mobilehub, amazon-mobile-hub

I'm using AWS Mobile Hub for my app. Downloaded the sample app relevant to my settings but I want to change the flow and screen of the sign in process.

Is there any good way of doing it besides changing the actual code? What is the best way to override that code? (I prefer override it in a way I could still get updates to this basic code)

The reason I want to change the code is that the sample app always request the "User Name", This is not always known to the user (he could forget it) so I want for example to implement forget password which could be retrieved by email or phone number etc (now everything is by "User Name").

The current default flow is very not understandable/make sense.

Comment: This is a limitation of the AWS Cognito service in their backend. The service currently doesn't support that, hence the AWSUserPoolSignIn doesn't interface it too.

Comment: @Karthikeyan I guess we would just implement the client flow by ourselves starting from the sample code app. :(